# How should the cppcms template hierarchy be used

Tags: web-development, c++, templates, hierarchy

I understand that the hierarchy, in cppcms for templates, goes skin (topmost, representing a namespace), then view (representing a class) and finally template (representing a function).

I want to know when I should use a skin and when I should use a view; would each page be a skin or would it be a skin per application, etc.

Could you explain when each should be used and could you give some examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read these tutorials carefuly:

- http://cppcms.com/wikipp/en/page/cppcms_1x_templates_gen
- http://cppcms.com/wikipp/en/page/cppcms_1x_tut_templates_inheritance

They cover the topic.

> I want to know when I should use a skin and when I should use a view; would each page be a skin or would it be a skin per application, etc.

Almost always you would use views... Skins are for "skinning" purposes or for totally
separate units like for example "general pages" and "administrator interface" that
share almost nothing - and it is yet non-mandatory.